# Get Silverlight 5 Deployment path (when running in the browser in Full Trust mode)

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, path, silverlight-5.0

Is there a way to get the deployment location of a Silverlight 5 application running in the browser in full trust mode?  I want to be able to extract some DLL's to the path and use them in the application, which apparently, Silverlight 5 supports.

I was planning to use an XBAP instead, but this seems to be dying a slow death, so SilverLight 5 seems the more logical option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that with 'the deployment location of a Silverlight 5 application' you are referring to where the Silverlight application is downloaded to on the client machine (not the website)

Even if extracting to the local folder would work I would not do it.

I'd have the Silverlight application download the XAP or DLLs. This way the Silverlight environment will keep those files in the cache and use them automatically when available and as long as there is no new version. You don't need to use Silverlight 5 for this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the P/Invoke functionality that has been introduced in Silverlight 5 RC. If this is the case, I have experienced a problem similar to yours. I solved it by bundling my native DLL as a resource in the Silverlight application XAP, and when starting the application I let the application copy the DLL to a local directory on my computer and add the local directory to the system path while the application is running.

A detailed description of how this was done can be found in [this blog post](http://cureos.blogspot.com/2011/09/pinvoke-bundling-native-dlls-in.html).

Albeit a little late, I hope this response can be of help anyway!

Regards,

Anders @ Cureos